# get id of specific option element through its value

Tags: javascript, select, parent

Here i have a few option element.One of them holding the value apple.I want to get the id of the option element which holds the value apple .So far i did the following.But can't get the parent element of a text node

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
Select a fruit:
<br>
<select id="mySelect" size="4">
  <option id='for_apple'>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Remove selected fruit</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var str="Apple";
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    if(x[x.selectedIndex].value == str){
      alert((x[x.selectedIndex].value).parentElement.id);
   }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parent element** will be the `select` element itself, right?

If you want to alert id of that specific option, then

Replace

```
if(x[x.selectedIndex].value == str){
  alert((x[x.selectedIndex].value).parentElement.id);
}
```

with

```
alert( x[x.selectedIndex].id );
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the parent element in your code i.e. `var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");` and the way you're trying to access a parent of a child `<option>` element is incorrect you can do it as `alert(element[index].parentElement);` where `element` is a HTML `<select>` element but this is unnecessary because element and parentElement both point to the same element.

You can do it like this.

```js
function removeSelectedFruit() {
    var value = 'Apple';
    var element = document.getElementById("fruits");
    var index = element.selectedIndex;
    if (index === -1) {
     return;
    }
    
    if (element.options[index].value === value) {
        alert(element.options[index].id);
        // or as gurvinder372 suggests alert(element[index].id);
        element.remove(index);
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Select A Fruit</h2>
  <form>
    <select id="fruits" size="4">
      <option id='for_apple'>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="removeSelectedFruit()">Remove Selected Fruit</button>
</div>
```